# mount.nfs requested NFS Version or transport protocol not supported -- Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nfs

I have nfs-common installed. I believe I have version 4 installed

Every time I try to mount the NFS  it gives the same error
mount.nfs:  requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported

I have looked all over online, and the fixes do not seem to match with my system

Most advice points to change version here >> /etc/nfsmount.conf      but I do not have that filepath

Comment: does anyone know where this file gets downloaded from since I am missing it? 

nfsmount.conf

Comment: I would suggest providing your full `mount` command and error message. Telling us you looked *all over online* isn't helpful unless you're specific; and that you allowed for the time-difference with what you found & the software stack you are using (ie. 18.04 means the 2018-April release making your Ubuntu system easy to date for changes/comparison with online documentation you find...)

Answer (score 0):

This error message likely has nothing to do with versions or protocols.

First make sure the machine where the file system resides is actually running an nfs server.  For example you can say `sudo service --status-all`; there should be a line there for nfs-kernel-server, with a + sign.

Also check that the server has an entry in /etc/exports that allows your client to remote mount it.  For example, if the client is called "foohost",
a line in the server's /etc/exports might look like this:

`/home foohost(all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check,rw,sync)`

Instead of foohost you could have * to allow any host to mount it, or an IP range, etc.  Type `man exports` to see the meaning of the various options in parentheses.

After editing /etc/exports, be sure to run `sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart` (also on the server) so the changes take effect.